# How does this user-defined function work with scipy integrate odeint?

Tags: python, function, scipy, user-defined-functions, ode

I am working on a project for electrical engineering where we plot the voltage over a capacitor in a RLC circuit as a function of time. I based my code on the following tutorial: [Python-ODE for RLC Circuit](http://dwightreid.com/blog/2013/03/06/python-solving-second-order-differential-equations/). My code is fully functional but I just want a better understanding of how the user defined function and the SciPy integrating function works. I have read the documentation but I still have some specific questions. Here is my code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint # for integrating ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for plotting commands
import numpy as np #For loadtxt and linspace modules

R,L,C,tl,numplot = np.loadtxt('UserInput_RLC_Values.txt',unpack=True)

def RLC(A,t):
    Vc,m=A
    V = 2.0 #voltageSource
    res=[m,(V-Vc-(m*R*C))/(L*C)]
    return res

time = np.linspace(0.0,tl,numplot)
vc,m = odeint(RLC,[0.0,0.0],time).T
```

Here are my questions:

1. What role are the parameter values A and t playing in the function RLC? Why is A assigned to both Vc (capacitor voltage) and m (dummy variable for v')? Is t even used?
2. When I call RLC function inside the odeint module why aren't there any parameters?
3. What does the .T at the end of the odeint module mean? I can't find anything about it in documentation.

Thanks for any insight on this. I hope this isn't a lazy question but I think fully understanding this will help me a great deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODE function passed to `odeint` needs to have the format `f(state, time)` where `time` is the independent variable and `state` the state vector. The corresponding (vector-valued) differential equation is `y'(t)=f(y(t),t)`

1. ) For the standard ODE solvers you need to convert higher-order equations into systems of first order. Here using `m` as momentum (?) variable, `m = dVc/dt`. Then `dm/dt = d²Vc/dt²` is the second derivative.

   If the input is `state = [ Vc, m ]` the output needs to be `[ dVc/dt, dm/dt ] = [ m, Eqn(t,Vc,m) ]` where `d²Vc/dt² = Eqn(t,Vc,dVc/dt)` is a form of the original equation.

   `t` just needs to be present in the argument list, even if the ODE is time-invariant.
2. )  You are passing the function as reference/address, not a function value
3. ) It means "transpose". The result of `odeint` is a list of state vectors, which are pairs of numbers. Transposing it transforms it into a pair of lists that can be assigned to a pair of variables.